# Need to remove duplicate lines using mawk (specifically)

Tags: awk, text-processing, mawk

I have a gawk command that works fine. But I have a machine with mawk installed and when I try to install gawk it complains about broken dependencies. I would like to change this line to mawk syntax.

```
awk -F '[|]{3}' 'BEGIN {OFS="|||"} !seen[$4]++ {print $4,$7,$3,$5,$6,$8,$9,$10,$11}' $1
```

Input File: It is a Three Pipe delimited file

```
A|||B|||C|||D|||E|||F|||G|||H|||I|||J|||K||||L|||M|||N|||O|||P|||Q|||R|||S||||T|||U
1|||2|||3|||4|||5|||6|||7|||8|||9|||10|||11|||12|||13|||14|||15|||16|||17|||18|||19
```

Comment: Pipe delimited file

Comment: I receive only the delimiters ||||||||||||||||||||||| without any data in between.

Comment: Can you show a real input sample and show us exactly how you ran the command for us to reproduce this behavior? I'm not able to reproduce this

Comment: Ran the command on bash with another file as pipe delimited input. I am not sure if this will help: mawk version 1.3.3

Comment: Wait, is the input file _a pipe delimited_ or _a three pipe delimited file_ (`-F '[|]{3}'`)?

Comment: 3 pipe delimited file..will edit the question.

Comment: @Inian, can you please run the above input in mawk?

Comment: Why is your input file mentioned `$1` in the question? `mawk` is a POSIX compliant `awk` which should produce the expected output for your sample.

Comment: Did you check your file for DOS style line endings? What does `file <input-file-name>` return?

Comment: ran dos2unix ..same output. 
file returns UTF-8 Unicode text, with very long lines

Comment: mawk probably has no knowledge yet about `[|]{3}`. Maybe you should write `-F "\\|\\|\\|"`

Comment: @kvantour Please write it as an answer and I will upvote it!! BTW thanks.

Comment: @MallikKumar see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX awk makes use of extended regular expressions which have the possiblility to define character duplication by means of `{m,n}`

> When an ERE matching a single character or an ERE enclosed in parentheses is followed by an interval expression of the format `{m}`, `{m,}`, or `{m,n}`, together with that interval expression it shall match what repeated consecutive occurrences of the ERE would match. The values of `m` and n are decimal integers in the range `0 <= m<= n<= {RE_DUP_MAX}`, where `m` specifies the exact or minimum number of occurrences and `n` specifies the maximum number of occurrences. The expression `{m}` matches exactly `m` occurrences of the preceding ERE, `{m,}` matches at least m occurrences, and `{m,n}` matches any number of occurrences between `m` and `n`, inclusive.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04)</sub>**

This method of duplication is unfortunately **not** supported by mawk as can be read from the [manual (Section 3 Regular Expressions)](https://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.txt).

So instead of defining the field separator `FS` by means of `-F '[|]{3}'`, you have to make use of `-F '[|][|][|]'` or `-F "\\|\\|\\|"`